# creating features for DataFrame from text file in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

Im looking to create features for a dataframe using feature_names.txt using the following code :

```
import pandas as pd
features = pd.read_csv("feature_names.txt", header= None)
dataset = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv")
dataset.columns = features.values
```

this outputs the following :

(id ,)  (age,)  (workclass,)    (fnlwgt,)   (education,)    (education-num,)    (marital-status,)   (occupation,)   (relationship,)

Im looking to remove the brackets and comma but have using the following code:

```
dataset.columns.str.replace("[()]", "")
```

this just makes all the headers nan

I would appreciate any help,
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If 'features' is a Series, you could try:

```
dataset.columns = features
```

If it's a dataframe, then:

```
dataset.columns = features['columnName']
```

Or if you want the index values as column names:

```
dataset.columns = features.index
```

Comment: amazing dataset.columns = features['columnName'] worked. thanks very much you saved me alot of time.